# screen flashes to white when first displaying a tab

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm creating React Native app in which I'm using React-native-navigation (v1).

It's a tab based app in which when I first switch tab by calling

```
 self.props.navigator.switchToTab({
                tabIndex: index - 1
              })
```

the screen flashes to white. On subsequent switching to that same tab, no flashes.

Any idea on how to get rid of the flash?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your Stack Navigator

```
presentation: "modal",
```

Full example:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        presentation: "modal", //added line
      }}
      cardStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} //also make the background transparent
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="getstarted" component={GetStarted} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</Provider>
```